# Using IFS with Arrayformula function in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, nested-if, ifs

I was wondering if its possible to use an IFS function inside the arrayfunction?

Im looking to have a drop down list populate an array depending on what is selected in the data validation.

the formula im using is:

=ARRAYFORMULA(IFs(H2="1st Quarter",'Pool 1 data'!C4:AG34,H2="2nd Quarter",'Pool 1 data'!C38:AG68,H2="3rd Quarter",'Pool 1 data'!C72:AG102,H2="4th Quarter",'Pool 1 data'!C106:AG136))

H2 is the drop down validation. So when "1st Quarter" is selected I want it to return the range c4:AG34, and when "2nd Quarter" is selected to return the range C38:AG68 and so on.

The current formula doesn't return anything. Am I way off or is there a different approach to make this happen?

Any advice would by greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
Here is the link to the spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fIRpI_f76ac4VNcpp0Ffvx_68lRLjFtaPrYFdgFEDs0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(H2="1st Quarter",'Pool 1 data'!C4:AG34, 
 IF(H2="2nd Quarter",'Pool 1 data'!C38:AG68, 
 IF(H2="3rd Quarter",'Pool 1 data'!C72:AG102,
 IF(H2="4th Quarter",'Pool 1 data'!C106:AG136, )))))
```

see: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/124685/186471

you may think that the behavior of **`IFS()`** is similar to **`IF()`** and the reason of having **`IFS()`** is to avoid nesting of multiple **`IF()`** but that's not so true. Yes, there are some common baselines however, there is a major difference when it comes to arrays. **`IFS()`** in a combination of arrayed output expects arrayed input - that's why you got returned single-cell output instead of arrayed output.

- let's say your **`IF()`** formula is like:

[image]

- "converting" it into **`IFS()`** will return this (because cell **A1** is not array/range):

[image]

- now let's add an arrayformula (ranged input):

[image]

- also note this behavior:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! that link helps explain where i went wrong.